# Why is the div with container class showing before the video tag in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why is the div with container class showing before the video tag in Bootstrap 4?

```
<div class='jumbotron'>
  <video width="320" height="240" >
     <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <div class='container'>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `z-index`. I needed to make sure the video had a higher `z-index` than the containing block. Without that it will appear as coming after that block because it is covered.